# Calling function in same module in Fortran90

Tags: function, dll, module, fortran, fortran90

I am new to Fortran90 and I haven't found an answer to a problem I have.
I have a module written in Fortran with the some functions inside a module.

Stripped down version:

```
module vdiStringFunctions
```

interface vdiString
    module procedure vdiString1Char
  end interface

contains
    character (128) function vdiString1Char(CSTRING, sVar1)
      character(*), intent(in) :: CSTRING, sVar1
      character(128) :: vdiStringGeneral
      character(len=128), dimension(0:9) :: stringArray

`stringArray(0) = adjustl(sVar1)
  vdiString1Char= vdiStringGeneral(CSTRING, stringArray)
end function vdiString1Char

character (128) function vdiStringGeneral(CSTRING, varArray)
  character(*), intent(in) :: CSTRING
  character(len=128), dimension(0:9), intent(in) :: varArray
  vdiStringGeneral = 'bla'
end function vdiStringGeneral`

end module vdiStringFunctions

When I try to compile with Intel Visual Fortran XE 2011 I get the following error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _VDISTRINGGENERAL referenced in function _VDISTRINGFUNCTIONS_mp_VDISTRING1CHAR  vdiStringFunctions.obj

Because the function vdiStringGeneral is in the same module than the calling vdiString1Char I do not get the problem.
When I move the vdiStringGeneral outside of the module it compiles without problems.

Because it should be used in a DLL all functions should be inside the module.
How can I get it to work that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the declaration of `vdiStringGeneral` in function `vdiString1Char`.
The interface for `vdiStringGeneral` is already explicit, because it is defined in the same module.
With the declaration you have now, the linker is looking for an external function.

Comment: Ah, sometimes it is that easy... Thanks for your help!